# Android: Programmatically animate between images in Gallery widget

Tags: android, image, widget, gallery

Note: As of Jellybean the gallery widget is deprecated. A [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) should be used instead.

---

I'd like to programmatically move between images in the Gallery widget, with animation.

I can change the currently displaying image using the `setSelection(int position)` method, however that does not animate. Then there's `setSelection(int position, bool animate)` but the extra boolean on the end there doesn't appear to do anything.

In the [source of Gallery](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/Gallery.java) it appears that it can handle DPAD key-presses, so a work-around I thought of was to fake the key-presses. Eg.

```
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT))
```

However I can't get this working for some reason. Anyone tried this?

I notice three of the widget's methods I'd love to use `moveNext()`, `movePrevious()` and `scrollToChild()` are all private and unusable.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just call the key press handler for the gallery directly:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

i.e

```
Gallery gallery = ((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery));

gallery.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, new KeyEvent(0, 0));
```

One important thing - this solution works only if child that is on left/right was already created, which means that it has to be 'visible'. If you have your image on fullscreen - consider setting spacing to -1 value.

Comment: Doesn't seems to work on sub-class Gallery, any idea who this is the case?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all on my HTC Desire. Just using it as a normal Gallery, triggered by a button press

Comment: Does this code work? I can't make it move. Do I miss something? And also, how can I make it move to a certain position, using it as many times as my pos in a "for"?

Answer (score 2):

Use gallery.setSelected(int);  Here is a simple example.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();
    Gallery g;
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos);
        g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        objects.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        objects.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        objects.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        objects.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        objects.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        objects.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        g.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, objects));
        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Log.i("", "selected " + arg2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            g.setSelection(i++);
    }

        private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mCtx;
        private List objects;

        public int getCount() {
            return this.objects.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList objects) {
            super();
            mCtx = context;
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView row = (ImageView) convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                row = new ImageView(mCtx);
                row.setBackgroundDrawable(objects.get(position));
            }
            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - Thank you for your response, however your solution doesn't appear to provide animation when changing between selected images. Animation is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can Animate using dispatchKeyEvent or calling onFling directly.

Here is sample code for dispatchKeyEvent:

```
KeyEvent evtKey = new KeyEvent(0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);
dispatchKeyEvent(evtKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I wrote my own version of the Gallery widget with the help of the code at [this site](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html).

I then wrote my own method which uses `mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance(distance);`

Now I can programmatically animate the gallery between images.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

mGallery.onFling(null,null, velocity,0);

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9140fd6af3061cdf#