# move the gallary elements automatically

Tags: android

Hi i want to move my gallary elements without tracking.for this give me some suggestions and example code.Thanks in adavance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the solution in [Android: Programmatically animate between images in Gallery widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731564/android-programmatically-animate-between-images-in-gallery-widget)